# Evaluating matrix factorization algorithms for Netflix

Tags: data-mining, algorithms, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

I've been trying to implement Simon Funk's movie recommendation algorithm explained [here](http://sifter.org/~simon/journal/20061211.html). I understand how the user and item factors are computed. However the evaluation method is not clearly explained. I checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31096/how-do-i-use-the-svd-in-collaborative-filtering/93281#93281) post also but there was no evaluation method there.

My Question:
Let's assume we divide the the user-rating matrix R into training(95%) and testing data-sets(5%): R_train and R_test and we use Simon Funk's algorithm to find the user factor matrix (U) and movie factor matrix (M) using the training data matrix: R_train=U*M. How do we evaluate algorithm using R_test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Tl;dr Frobenius norm, limited to known entries.

Let $P$ be the matrix of predictions (so $P_{u,m}$ is the predicted rating for user $u$ and movie $m$).

Let $R^{train}$ and $R^{test}$ be the training and test sets of data. For convenience, I'll use notation $R^{test}_{u,m}$ to mean the rating of user $u$ of movie $m$ in the test set, but note that $R^{test}$ is ***not*** a matrix, because it's *sparse*: 99% of the entries are missing. Most users have not rated most movies. Only a tiny number of $(u,m)$ pairs are actually present in $R^{test}$.

The error of prediction matrix $P$ is

> $\displaystyle\sum_{(u,m) \in R^{test}} (R^{test}_{u,m} - P_{u,m})^2$

That is, the sum over the squared error of known entries in the test set.

`# Pseudocode for calculating error
p = ... # prediction matrix, indexed by [u][m]
r_test = ... # list of (user, movie, rating) tuples
error = 0.0
for (u, m, r) in r_test:
  error += (r - predictions[u][m])^2`

#### Important note on splitting test/train set

When splitting up the data into training and test sets, you should randomly select (user, movie) pairs, ***not*** select random users or movies. The whole idea of "collaborative filtering" (for Netflix) is to predict ratings for movies you *haven't* watched based on the ratings you provided for ones you *have*. If a user is present only in the testing set, the model cannot possibly be basing predictions based on their other ratings.

#### I need more help on the Netflix problem and SVD

See my [other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33142/what-happens-when-you-apply-svd-to-a-collaborative-filtering-problem-what-is-th/35460#35460) for a description of the netflix problem and matrix-factoring approaches to it.

Comment: Thank you Pete for your answer, it made the problem clearer. I do not understand why we use predictions[u][m] in the for loop though. Why is the test user in the generated user factor matrix? Do we evaluate the algorithm using the factor matrices obtained from the whole dataset? I am considering the case where I split the matrix so that the training matrix has 95% of the users(row-wise) and the rest of the users are in the testing matrix.

Comment: @Dolphi See my updates. For one, you're splitting up test/train the wrong way. Users should be in both the test and train set (otherwise we're not training on any of their ratings).